# Delegating events to a parent view in Backbone

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, events, backbone.js, delegation

My view, `TuneBook`, has several child views of type `ClosedTune`. I also have separate full page views for each tune, `OpenTune`. The same events are bound within `ClosedTune` and `OpenTune`, so I've designed my app so that they both inherit from a shared 'abstract' view `Tune`.

To make my app more scaleable I would like the events for each `ClosedTune` to be delegated to `TuneBook`, but for maintainability I would like the same handlers (the ones stored in `Tune`) to be used by `TuneBook` (although they'd obviously need to be wrapped in some function).

The problem I have is, within `TuneBook`, finding the correct `ClosedTune` to call the handler on. What's a good way to architect this, or are there other good solutions for delegating events to a parent view?

*Note* - not a duplicate of [Backbone View: Inherit and extend events from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403675/backbone-view-inherit-and-extend-events-from-parent) (which is about children inheriting from a parent class, whereas I'm asking about children which are child nodes of the parent in the DOM)

Comment: If the events are gonna be executed by handlers in model `Tune` why you want to make the detour `ChildView -> ParentView -> Model`.. you can execute the `Model.handler` directly from the `ChildView`.. In other hand you can use the `Model` as the messenger: you can modify the state of the Model from the ChildView and let the ParentView to listen to this modification.

Comment: @fguillen It's a lot less efficient to bind the events (perhaps I should be clear I mean DOM events rather than Backbone custom events) to each child view's DOM node rather than just once to the parent view's DOM node. On the 300 row table generated by my app performance is noticeably sluggish when binding directly to each row. What I need is `ParentView -> [childView] -> childModel`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your parent view (extending also from `Backbone.Events`), I would bind `onEvent` to the DOM event. On trigger, it would fire a backbone event including some "id" attribute that your child views know (presumably some row id?).

```
var TuneBook = Backbone.View.extend(_.extend({}, Backbone.Events, {
    events: {
        "click .tune .button": "clickHandler"
    },
    clickHandler: function (ev) {
        this.trigger('buttonClick:' + ev.some_id_attr, ev);
    },

}));
```

Child views would then naturally subscribe to the parent views event that concerns them. Below I do it in `initialize` passing the parent view as well as that special id attribute you used before in `options`.

```
var ClosedTune = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        options.parent.on('buttonClick:' + options.id, this.handler, this);
    },

    handler: function (ev) {
        ...
    },

});
```

You can of course also set up similar subscribers on `Tune` or `OpenTune`.

Comment: This approach uses the parent view as an "event aggregator" which is a good pattern to follow.

Alternatively, you can also create a separate object that's your event aggregator and pass that to your child views.  Then your children don't need to traverse the DOM to find the right object on which to listen for events.  

For more info on event aggregators, see this article:
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/

Comment: This looks perfect. Will try it out tonight

Comment: I implemented this almost exactly, with the sole alteration that I attached `ClosedTune`'s event listeners within the addOne() method of `TuneBook` to a) avoid having to pass references to parent b) enable use of `ClosedTune` within other contexts

Comment: Can we pass data on click?

Answer (score 7):

Here are a couple of possibilities.

## 1. Centralized: store `ClosedTune` objects in the `TuneBook` instance

1. Store a reference to each `ClosedTune` in `tune_book.tunes`.  How you populate `tune_book.tunes` is up to you; since you mentioned an adder method on `TuneBook`, that's what I've illustrated below.
2. In the `TuneBook` event handler, retrieve the `ClosedTune` from `tune_book.tunes` by using something like the `id` attribute of the event target as the key.  Then call the `Tune` or `ClosedTune` handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/p5QMT/1/

```
var Tune = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: "tune",

  click_handler: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.id + " clicked");
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(
      '<a href="" class="button">' + this.id + '</a>'
    );

    return this;
  }
});

var ClosedTune = Tune.extend({});

var OpenTune = Tune.extend({
  events: {
    "click .button" : 'click_handler'
  }
});

var TuneBook = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .tune .button" : 'click_handler'
  },

  click_handler: function (event) {
    var tune = this.options.tunes[
      $(event.target).closest(".tune").attr('id')
    ];

    tune.click_handler( event );
  },

  add_tune: function (tune) {
    this.options.tunes[tune.id] = tune;
    this.$el.append(tune.render().el);
  },

  render: function () {
    $("body").append(this.el);
    return this;
  }
});

var tune_book = new TuneBook({
  tunes: {}
});

[1, 2, 3].forEach(function (number) {
  tune_book.add_tune(new ClosedTune({
    id: "closed-tune-" + number
  }));
});

tune_book.render();

var open_tune = new OpenTune({
  id: "open-tune-1"
});

$("body").append(open_tune.render().el);
```

## 2. Decentralized: associate the view object with the DOM object using `jQuery.data()`

1. When you create a `ClosedTune`, store a reference to it, e.g. `this.$el.data('view_object', this)`.
2. In the event listener, retrieve the `ClosedTune`, e.g. `$(event.target).data('view_object')`.

You can use the same exact handler for `ClosedTune` (in `TuneBook`) and `OpenTune`, if you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/jQZNF/1/

```
var Tune = Backbone.View.extend({
  className: "tune",

  initialize: function (options) {
    this.$el.data('view_object', this);
  },

  click_handler: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var tune =
      $(event.target).closest(".tune").data('view_object');

    console.log(tune.id + " clicked");
  },

  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(
      '<a href="" class="button">' + this.id + '</a>'
    );

    return this;
  }
});

var ClosedTune = Tune.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.constructor.__super__.initialize.call(this, options);
  }
});

var OpenTune = Tune.extend({
  events: {
    "click .button" : 'click_handler'
  }
});

var TuneBook = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .tune .button": Tune.prototype.click_handler
  },

  add_tune: function (tune) {
    this.$el.append(tune.render().el);
  },

  render: function () {
    $("body").append(this.el);
    return this;
  }
});

var tune_book = new TuneBook({
  tunes: {}
});

[1, 2, 3].forEach(function (number) {
  tune_book.add_tune(new ClosedTune({
    id: "closed-tune-" + number
  }));
});

tune_book.render();

var open_tune = new OpenTune({
  id: "open-tune-1"
});

$("body").append(open_tune.render().el);
```

## Response to comment

> I considered option 1 but decided against it as I already have a collection of tune models in the tunebook and didn't want another object I'd need to keep in sync

I guess it depends what kind of housekeeping / syncing you feel the need to do, and why.

> (e.g. in TuneModel.remove() I would need to remove the view from tunebook's list of views... would probably need events to do this, so an event only solution starts to look more attractive).

*Why* do you feel that you "need to remove the view from tunebook's list of views"?  (I'm not suggesting you shouldn't, just asking why *you* want to.)  Since you do, how do you think @ggozad's approach differs in that respect?

Both techniques store `ClosedTune` objects in the `TuneBook` instance.  In @ggozad's technique it's just hidden behind an abstraction that perhaps makes it less obvious to you.

In my example they're stored in a plain JS object (`tune_book.tunes`).  In @ggozad's they're stored in the `_callbacks` structure used by `Backbone.Events`.

Adding a `ClosedTune`:

1.

```
this.options.tunes[tune.id] = tune;
```

2.

```
this.on('buttonClick:' + tune.id, tune.handler, tune);
```

If you want to get rid of a `ClosedTune` (say you remove it from the document with `tune.remove()` and you want the view object gone completely), using @ggozad's approach will leave an orphaned reference to the `ClosedTune` in `tune_book._callbacks` unless you perform the same kind of housekeeping that would make sense with the approach I suggested:

1.

```
delete this.options.tunes[tune.id];

tune.remove();
```

2.

```
this.off("buttonClick:" + tune.id);

tune.remove();
```

The first line of each example is optional -- depending if you want to clean up the `ClosedTune` objects or not.

> Option 2 is more or less what I'm doing right now, but (for other reasons) I also store the model as a data attribute on view.$el, and I can't help feeling that there's got to be a better way than storing references all over the place.

Well, it ultimately comes down to your preference for how to structure things.  If you prefer storing the view objects in a more centralized fashion, you can store them in the `TuneBook` instance instead of using `jQuery.data`.  See #1: Centralized.

One way or another you're storing references to the `ClosedTune` objects: using `jQuery.data`, or in a plain object in the `TuneBook`, or in `_callbacks` in the `TuneBook`.

If you like @ggozad's approach for reasons that you understand, go for it, but it's not magic.  As it's presented here I'm not sure what advantage is supposed to be provided by the extra level of abstraction compared to the more straightforward version I present in #1.  If there is some advantage, feel free to fill me in.

Comment: I considered option 1 but decided against it as I already have a collection of tune models in the tunebook and didn't want another object I'd need to keep in sync (e.g. in TuneModel.remove() I would need to remove the view from tunebook's list of views... would probably need events to do this, so an event only solution starts to look more attractive). Option 2 is more or less what I'm doing right now, but (for other reasons) I also store the model as a data attribute on view.$el, and I can't help feeling that there's got to be a better way than storing references all over the place.

Comment: @wheresrhys I don't know if it was a factor in your selection, but I've corrected the stupid errors that were in my earlier code examples.  I updated my answer with a response to your comment (see "Response to comment" section).

Comment: Cheers for the thorough answer. It's true that it's easy to see events as a magic bullet that loosely couples objects without any downsides, and you're right that I should give more thought to declutternig the callbacks when removing objects. Nevertheless events is still my preferred option. Having the duplicate references to the views abstracted away feels cleaner and less tempting for me or other developers to misuse. As for using $.data I'm always wary of using anything that queries the DOM unless absolutely necessary as DOM interactions are relatively slow.

Comment: @wheresrhys "less tempting for me or other developers to misuse" -- not sure what you mean here. "As for using $.data ..." -- I think you misunderstand what `jQuery.data()` does. You didn't specify what you're actually using where `ev.some_id_attr` appears in your `clickHandler`, so I assume you're using a property of a DOM object you have access to at that point, e.g. `ev.target.id`. `jQuery.data()` isn't a DOM operation, it just uses a property of a DOM object (e.g. `ev.target`) as a key to read data from a JS object. Calling `this.trigger()` does the same -- reads data from a JS object.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution I have taken from this [article](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) (@dave-cadwallader comment).

Extend an general backbone events object and store it in a reference `vent`:

```
var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Pass it to parent view:

```
var parentView = new ParentView({vent: vent});
```

The child view will trigger an event:

```
ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({    
  initialize: function(options){
    this.vent = options.vent;
  },

  myHandler: function(){
    this.vent.trigger("myEvent", this.model);
  }
});
```

And the parent view is listening to the child event:

```
ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function(options){
        this.vent = options.vent;
        this.vent.on("myEvent", this.onMyEvent);

        let childView = new ChildView({vent: this.vent});
    },

    onMyEvent: function(){
        console.log("Child event has been ");
    }
});
```

Disclaimer - pay attention that the `vent` object has to be injected to every view so you will find in this article better design patterns to make use of.