# The best way to undelegate events once a view is no longer needed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it a bad practice to call `undelegateEvents()` in the view `remove()` method? Why wasn't it included by default by the backbone guys?

I realized I am falling into so many binding issues, when simply reinitializing a view variable. Although `undelegateEvents()` is being called automatically when a new view is created, it is trying to undelegate events for the newly instantiated view, not the previous one. Therefore, unless manually calling it every time, ghost event callbacks remain alive and screw up my apps.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429648/backbone-js-how-to-unbind-from-events-on-model-remove/10433015#10433015

Comment: Are you re-using an `el` when switching views rather than creating new ones? The jQuery `delegate` is bound to the view's `el`.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, I oftentimes reuse the same DOM container, and give it to the view, instead of creating and attaching a new one every so often. That's why removing the ghost callbacks is of critical importance

Comment: Then calling `undelegateEvents` during cleanup is to be expected and fine. `remove` doesn't `undelegateEvents` because it kills off the whole `el` and there'd be no point.

Comment: If you have a custom `remove()` method, please post it in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to call `undelegateEvents()` in the view `remove()` method?

It's not necessary unless you're implementing your own `remove()` and you don't call `Backbone.View.remove()` or `this.$el.remove()`.  That's if you're using jQuery, at least.  Calling `remove()` on a Backbone view will call `jQuery.remove()` which will remove all of the DOM event listeners anyway.

> I realized I am falling into so many binding issues, when simply reinitializing a view variable.

A lot of people seem to use Backbone.Events like it's some kind of magic that they don't need to clean up after, e.g.:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend( {

  initialize : function ( options ) {

    // `on()` or `bind()`

    this.model.on( 'something', this.render, this );

  }

} );
```

See my answer on [Delegating events to a parent view in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485610/delegating-events-to-a-parent-view-in-backbone/10486571#10486571)

Is it possible that the ghost event issues you're experiencing are with Backbone events and not DOM events?

If you keep the model object around but want to get rid of that view object or its Backbone event registrations, you have to do `view.model.off( null, null, this );`.  You have to unbind the events that you've registered on any external objects.  If you want, you could override `Backbone.View.remove()` and do it there, but by default that method is just shorthand for `view.$el.remove()`.