# Backbone multiple views on one element

Tags: events, backbone.js, view

I'm having an issue with view events being applied multiple times on the same view.  I know this is because I am binding multiple views to the same el - so when I load one view, go to another, and then come back to the first one, it's applying the events again on top of the existing ghosted ones, since it's creating a new WhateverView() from the router each time.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734210/the-best-way-to-undelegate-events-once-a-view-is-no-longer-needed) I need to call view.model.off( null, null, this ); to reset the events.  Unfortunately...I'm not using models for any of my views.  Maybe this is completely the wrong way to go about things, but right now my views are essentially just different static pages in an SPA. I will have actual data eventually and I'll be using models/collections, but for now I just want different static pages in my app to be rendered
in some container.  I'm using requirejs and the text plugin and it works great so far...except for this event thing.

I've also tried calling `this.undelegateEvents();` before I render each view (in case the view in question had already been rendered at least once before) but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are attaching event listeners to elements each time you create the view.  I was able to resolve this problem in an app by doing the following:

```
$( '#coolbutton').off('click').on('click', coolFunc);
```

Using the events object, calling:

```
this.undelegateEvents();
this.$el.removeData().unbind();
```

when removing the view works as well.

Comment: I have this in my view: events: {
    'click .collapse-section': 'collapseSection'
}, so where would I put that code?  It looks like you're avoiding the events object altogether?

Comment: When you debug, is collapseSection() getting called once for each time the view has been created?

Comment: I usually destroy my views like this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11534056/1742747](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11534056/1742747)

Comment: Yeh..if I go to another view and then come back to this view 5 times, it will apply the function 5 times to .collapse-section.  So I click .collapse-section and it will then run that function 5 times.

Comment: Ah! this.$el.removeData().unbind(); did it.  Thanks!

Comment: same problem here...the clicked element though references a classname defined in the view...not el...any idea how to tackle https://codepen.io/deoman12/pen/rNWPKdo?editors=0010

Comment: I get removeData is not a function...error in the console

Comment: I fixed the above error  message...but reove data still not working