# How to override tagName, id, className, el, and events from sub views?

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Let's say I have the following Backbone structure:

```
 var BrowserView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: 'body',
   events: {
     click : "onClickEvent"
   },

   initialize: function () {
     this.collections = [];
   }
 });

 var FileBrowserView = BrowserView.extend({
   el: '#file',
   className: 'file-class',
   events: {
     click: "onFileClick",
     mouseover: "onMouseOver"   
   },

   initialize: function () {
     this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this);     
   }
 });
```

I need to override tagName, id, className, el properties from child View and combine events object from child view with parent view.
How can I do that?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403675/backbone-view-inherit-and-extend-events-from-parent once you inherit the event you can override the properties and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the *tagName*, *id*, *className* and *el* properties you can simply override them by setting new values as you did.
For the *events*, you can use the same trick you used for the *initialize* method simply because the *events* key can be a function.

```
events: function(){
  return _.extend({}, this.constructor.__super__.events, {
    // list of events
  });
}
```

Note that this won't work for several levels of inheritance, so, the exact formula would be:

```
events: function(){
  return _.extend({}, _.result(this.constructor.__super__, 'events'), {
    // list of events
  });
}
```