# Backbone view override parent event function

Tags: backbone.js

Is it possible to override `closeClick` function in child view? When `.close` is clicked, only run child's `closeClick` function instead of the parent.

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events:{
    "click .close": "closeClick"
 },

 closeClick: function(){
    //do parent stuff
 }
});

var ChildView = ParentView.extendable.extend({
  events:{
    "click .close": "closeClick",
    //more child events
  },

  closeClick: function(){
     //only do child stuff not parent when .close is clicked
  }
});
```

Comment: I searched and tried this solution however not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403675/backbone-view-inherit-and-extend-events-from-parent

Comment: I tried to write       return _.extend({},ParentView.prototype.events,{
          'click' : 'onclickChild'
      }); inside the child view, it cannot override the parent closeClick function, seems it can only extend more events

Comment: Function name in child is whatever,  just the child function can override the parent function. like if child function called "onclickChild", once .close on click, run onclickChild not the function in parent "closeClick", thanks!

Comment: the function named "closeClick" inherited from parentview is overridden by the childView. So I guess childViews "closeClick" should get called.Just check out $el of childView if it refers to child's control with class "close"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written will work fine with normal Backbone `.extend`. Don't know what this strange `extendable` statement is though - that's probably what's breaking it.

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
    "click .close": "closeClick"
 },

 closeClick: function(){
    //do parent stuff
 }
});

var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
  events: function() {
    var parentEvents = _.result(ParentView.prototype, 'events');
    return _.extend({
        'keyup input': 'someOtherChildEvent'
    }, parentEvents);
  },

  closeClick: function() {
     //only do child stuff not parent when .close is clicked
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello There thanks for your answer. Just wonder can I bind "click .close": "childCloseClick" in ChildView? like     return _.extend({ "click .close": "childCloseClick",
        'keyup input': 'someOtherChildEvent'
    }, parentEvents);

Comment: Np, if you repeat `click .close` there with a different method name, it will override the parent's one, so it will call `childCloseClick` instead of `closeClick` in the child view